# RichEditBox : set a style only for the characters that are about to be written

Tags: xaml, windows-8, textedit

I'm trying to create a simple text editor in a Windows 8 application, like a simple OneNote. I can set font size, font color and font style, but the problem is that it's applied to the whole content of my RichEditBox, even to the text that has already been written. But I would like that, when I select "Italic" for exemple, only the future characters should be written in Italic, and the words and characters already written remain in the style they were.
It's quite difficult to describe.
Do I use the good XAML element (RichEditBox) ? Is there a method to select the actual position of the writer in the RichEditBox ?

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

Try this button event. `rebTextNote` is RichEditBox object.

```
using Windows.UI.Text;

public void btnItalic_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ITextCharacterFormat format = rebTextNote.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat;
    if (format.Italic != FormatEffect.On)
        format.Italic = FormatEffect.On;
    else
        format.Italic = FormatEffect.Off;
}
```